# Radcombobox AllowCustomText=true,how to only enter type from existing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radcombobox

Hi every One I have a Radcombobox now client requirment is to make combobox searchable means user can search from combobox. for that purpose i have used AllowCustomtext=true property and its working fine but problem is that user now can enter any data and combobox is accepting any value i want to restrict user to enter data only from options which are populated means user should not be able to enter any raw data just user can enter from option available in combobox??

Comment: RadCombobox?  Are you using the Telerik ASP.NET controls?  Which version?

Comment: yupp we are using  telerik controls 2010  Jeff Fritz :)

Answer (score 2):

As of the 2013 version of the controls, you can use the RadSearchBox which is designed for exactly this type of interaction:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/searchbox/examples/propertyexplorer/defaultcs.aspx

For previous versions of the RadComboBox, you can see this at work in a demo at:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/autocompleteclientside/defaultcs.aspx

You want to set AllowCustomText to FALSE and set MarkFirstMatch to TRUE and it should filter appropriately without allowing the custom text.